# how to eliminate redundancy within a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file as follows

```
{
  "question": "yellow skin around wound from cat bite. why?",
  "answer": "this may be the secondary result of a resolving bruise but a cat bite is a potentially serious and complicated wound and should be under the care of a physician.",
  "tags": [
    "wound care"
  ]
},
{
  "question": "yellow skin around wound from cat bite. why?",
  "answer": "see your doctor with all deliberate speed. or go to an urgent care center or a hospital emergency room. do it fast!",
  "tags": [
    "wound care"
  ]
},
```

As you can see the redudant parts are on only the "question" part of the keys, but the answer differs from one to another, what it means is that this data was extracted from a forum, and it holds different answers  to the same  question,is there a way using pyton to eliminate the redundant parts or group the answers together.
thank you

Comment: load up the file using the `json` module and then go item by item and add/concat them to a dict

Comment: What is the output you would expect for this input? Do you care about the `"tags"` field? What have you tried? Btw, the snippet is not a valid JSON document, is that part of a larger JSON, maybe enclosed in a JSON array?

Comment: Mr jdhesa , actually it is a part of a larger json file, that containes about 1 Million line, it's for a dataset for my project, and i'm trying to clean it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort of grouping is required. Many ways to do that, including functions from the `itertools` module, external modules like `pandas`, and other sources. Here's one approach using a builtin structure, `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import json

data = json.loads(rawdata)
questions = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    question = row.pop('question')
    questions[question].append(row)
```

The result will be a dictionary `questions` (a `defaultdict` to be precise) keyed by questions, with values giving the resulting answers and tags. One downside is this destructively alters your original parsed JSON data. You can remedy that in several ways, which I'll omit for brevity.

Here is a simplified version of the `questions` dictionary that results:

```py
{'yellow skin ...why?': [{'answer': 'this may be the secondary result of a '
                                    'resolving bruise but a cat bite is a '
                                    'potentially serious and complicated wound '
                                    'and should be under the care of a '
                                    'physician.',
                          'tags': ['wound care']},
                         {'answer': 'see your doctor with all deliberate '
                                    'speed. or go to an urgent care center or '
                                    'a hospital emergency room. do it fast!',
                          'tags': ['wound care']}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas here

```
import pandas as pd
a='''[{
  "question": "yellow skin around wound from cat bite. why?",
  "answer": "this may be the secondary result of a resolving bruise but a cat bite is a potentially serious and complicated wound and should be under the care of a physician.",
  "tags": [
    "wound care"
  ]
},
{
  "question": "yellow skin around wound from cat bite. why?",
  "answer": "see your doctor with all deliberate speed. or go to an urgent care center or a hospital emergency room. do it fast!",
  "tags": [
    "wound care"
  ]
}]'''
df = pd.read_json(a)
df.groupby(['question'])['answer'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: this methode doesn't really eliminate the redundancy

Comment: And why is that?@HaithamHachicha. You will get answers grouped together in a list for the same question being the key in final dictionary